# Spacemacs find text (SPC /) not working

Tags: spacemacs

I recently installed Spacemacs on Windows. The "smart search" command `SPC /` does not work. When I press `SPC /` I get the error:

`Wrong type argument: commandp, helm-do-grep`

There seem to be some issue that mention this - https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8463

Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 4):

If my understanding is correct, your spacemacs is not finding ag or grep. Spacemacs uses ag, grep, ack, pt for search. If ag is not found it falls back to grep and so on. Grep, ack are *nix commands. You probably have to install cygwin and add it to the path.

But the best way is to install this port of ag for windows and add it to the path. [ag for windows](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/the-silver-searcher-for-windows.html)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a solution, but it is a workaround that I ended up using. I was used to using Spacemacs on Mac. I installed it on windows and encountered the above error. On Windows it was using `grep` by default for searching, whereas on Mac it was using `ag`.

I installed `ag` on Windows that the search is back to working now. I installed `ag` following the instructions on [here](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/wiki/Windows). It uses [scoop](http://scoop.sh/) for the installation which is installed via Powershell.

Comment: I had the same problem on MacOS and solved it by installing `ag`, thanks!